# DataStax Cassandra seems expensive, is there a best practice configuration to use Apache Cassandra in Production?

Tags: cassandra

DataStax seems expensive. Is there a best practice configuration that is available to use Apache Cassandra in production? I am trying to setup Cassandra on EC2.

Thanks

Answer (score 11):

Instead of giving you a commercial for some other product, let me give you some practical advice when choosing to go with OSS vs Commerical licensed products.

You have two things to spend when using any technology. Time or money. Ultimately time is money, but for the sake of this let's say they are different. By your question, you have more time so let's focus on that.

1. Spend the time to learn the fundamentals. The term black magic is FUD. Some of the world's largest workloads are running on Cassandra. You can do it too.
2. Seek out peers and learn from those who have been successful. There are organizations that have been running Cassandra in prod for years.
3. Focus on a single use case/project. Nothing worse than trying to replace all of your infrastructure with a new technology when you are learning. Pick one thing and become proficient. Use that experience for the next projects.

You can get some free training at DataStax Academy. http://academy.datastax.com

Learn from peers by watching talks from the community of awesome users.
 You can find something in these 135 talks here: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLm-EPIkBI3YoiA-02vufoEj4CgYvIQgIk

If you need to ask questions. Stack Overflow, the Cassandra mailing list, and DataStax Academy Slack are all good resources.

Using a commercial product or spending the time is up to you, but don't let anyone try to convince you that it's too hard and you should use something else.  We are all here to help if we can.

Comment: Patrick is correct that Cassandra is usable out-of-the-box, and no "black magic" is needed to start using it correctly. However, you will have to install it yourself as no AMIs are available (that's not a problem for most people...), and if and when you'll want to squeeze every once of performance from your setup -  and especially if you care specifically about low latency - you will need to learn about tweaking it for best performance. Definitely many guides available on the web for that (if you have the time) and many consulting companies to do it for you (if you have the money).

Comment: This is a passive-aggressive response from a Scylla developer to try and pull you away from Cassandra, Naveen. It takes 5-7 years for a distributed system to stabilize enough for most prod deployments. Cassandra will do what you need. You can do it.

Comment: I think it's a fair point to make that many people have hard time learning the ins and outs of Apache Cassandra best practices for production deployments, which is exactly why enterprise offerings like DataStax Enterprise and ScyllaDB offer so much value. Of course, it never hurts to learn fundamentals and the resources you recommended are definitely worth looking at.

Comment: Appreciate all the help. I started learning by going through a Cassandra Certification course on Udemy. All the resources pointed to are of great help. We have been using instaClustr and are trying to bring the capability inhouse, during which I have been investigating our options. The team and I , will definitely learn.

Answer (score 7):

Disclaimer: I'm a ScyllaDB employee.

There are several alternative to operate Cassandra/Scylla like workloads.

1. Use OpenSource Cassandra, with best practices. Most of them, unfortunately, where created couple of years ago. So you'll need to learn the black magic of tuning JVM and Cassandra loads.
   https://tobert.github.io/pages/als-cassandra-21-tuning-guide.html
   There are no "official" AMIs on AWS for recent releases of Cassandra.
2. Use Scylla OpenSource. It is a drop replacement for Cassandra. Scylla autotunes itself, to minimize the intervention of the operator in the day-to-day operations. Also, Scylla provides opensoure AMIs for EC2 deployment, so, all you need is an AWS account.
   Scylla is a C++ implementation of Cassandra, which benefits from the great (and costly) resources on AWS. Thus, offer a better ops/$$ ratio. Scylla highly recommends the usage of I3 instances, you'd be using contemporary CPU technology, excellent I/O (NVMe based) and lots of memory at the fraction of the cost of other EC2 instances.
   You can read more about it here:
   http://www.scylladb.com/2017/05/10/faster-and-better-what-to-expect-running-scylla-on-aws-i3-instances/

ScyllaDB is committed to provide opensource, optimized AMI versions.

3. Buy enterprise licenses from DataStax or Scylla.
4. Hire consultants to help you install a Cassandra setup.
   Companies like "the last pickle" or Pythian can help you in that regard.
5. Use DBaaS offerings from the following companies:
   Scylla:

IBM Compose: https://www.compose.com/databases/scylladb

Joyent Triton:https://www.joyent.com/blog/free-trial-managed-scylladb-beta-on-triton

Scylla and Cassandra
Instaclustr: https://www.instaclustr.com/

Hope this helps.